# For loop without any statement

Tags: c, for-loop

This program tells whether a given input is prime or not but I don't understand what exactly the for loop does here? It has no brackets and no statements in it.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter an integer number (> 1): ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 1) {
        printf("Invalid input. Quit!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    int d;
    for (d = 2; n % d != 0; d++)
        ;

    if (d == n)
        printf("%d is prime\n", n);
    else
        printf("%d divides into %d\n", d, n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try putting in some small numbers for d and n then running it in an IDE or by hand on paper.  Pay attention to the value of d before and after the loop runs.

Comment: It is conventional to put the semicolon indicating an empty loop body on a line on its own indented.  The loop is expensive — unnecessarily expensive (don't expect to break any speed records using it).

Comment: An empty statement and a missing statement are not the same thing. The `for` loop does have a statement; it is the empty statement.

Comment: A number is prime if it have no any divisor except 2 and itself.  We check from `2 -> n` when for `index: d` not changes it means, number entered: `n` have not any more divisor.

Comment: The key is the semicolon `;` at the end of the `for` statement: it is the loop body, it just means "do nothing". Personally I would prefer empty `{ }` or at least placing the semicolon on the next line, indented. The loop could also be written as `int d = 2; while (n % d != 0) { ++d; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't need a body, the purpose is just to increment `d` until the condition `n % d != 0` is false (i.e. when `n % d == 0` is true). It's not doing anything with `d` during this process.

At the end of the loop, `d` will be the lowest factor of `n`. If `d == n` it means that `n` doesn't have any factors other than itself and 1 (which isn't checked, since the loop starts at `d = 2`), i.e. it's prime.

Answer (score 0):

The loop still checks the condition `n % d != 0` and increases `d` at every cycle. As soon as `n` can be divided by `d` without reminder, `d` will not increase anymore and the loop exits. So you have your `d`.

Then you can find whether the number is prime with the condition following: If there was's a factor found lower than n, it's not prime. It's prime if there was no other factor.